# error message `unexpected token: '{'` in json document

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to specify an url in an app written in javascript that returns the weather based on the api (the url), made up of a sting and some variables. After entering the following original code, I had received the error message `Missing { before function body`.

```js
function apiurl() {
  var str = this._baseURL + '=' + (this.apikey);
  str = str.replace('=', '');
  console.log(str);
}

let a = this._getWeather(function(apiurl), function(weather) {
  if (weather) {
    this._load_forecast(weather);
  }
  // get the main object to update the display
  deskletObj.displayForecast();
  deskletObj.displayCurrent();
  deskletObj.displayMeta();
});
},
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

I have since changed the code to

```js
let a = this._getWeather {
  (function(apiurl), function(weather) {
    if (weather) {
      this._load_forecast(weather);
    }
    // get the main object to update the display
    deskletObj.displayForecast();
    deskletObj.displayCurrent();
    deskletObj.displayMeta();
  });
},
```

And received the error message `unexpected token: '{'`

my hope is to find out the proper syntax of the json code so as to allow the api (the url for the website where the data is procured) to function.

Update - I have made the following changes based on the following comments.

I changed the code to this

```
    function apiurl() {
    let apiurl = this._baseURL + '=' + (this.apikey);
   //var str = this._baseURL + '=' + (this.apikey);
    str = str.replace('=','');
    console.log(str); 
    }
```

and got the following from the logfile

```
    info t=2024-01-30T10:18:19Z bbcwx (instance 34): refreshing forecast at 10:18:19
    error t=2024-01-30T10:18:19Z this is undefined
    info t=2024-01-30T10:18:19Z Loaded desklet bbcwx@oak-wood.co.uk in 65 ms
```

I made the following update after a comment from 3limin4t0r:

```
    function weatherApiURL {
    weatherApiUrl.path = "https://api.weather.com/v2/pws/observations/current?stationId=MyStationId&format=json&units=e&apiKey=MyApiKey"
    weatherApiUrl.toString()
    //let apiurl = this._baseURL + '=' + (this.apikey);
    //var str = this._baseURL + '=' + (this.apikey);
    //str = str.replace('=','');
   console.log(str); 
   }
   this._getWeather(weatherApiURL(), function (weather) {
   if (weather) {
    this._load_forecast(weather);
   }
   // get the main object to update the display
   deskletObj.displayForecast();
   deskletObj.displayCurrent();
   deskletObj.displayMeta();
   });

   },
```

Comment: `function (apiurl)` This function has no body.

Comment: you are missing the meaning of what you are doing. you are attempting to invoke a function but you randomly tried to use `{` instead of `(` and you passed as argument what looked like a function definition (malformed). I'm pretty sure you were just expected to pass the `apiurl` alone.

Comment: Maybe you mean `this._getWeather(apiurl(), function (weather) { ... })` - make sure apiurl returns a url I guess.

Comment: thank you.I think I might have an idea as to how to fix this.

Comment: You have a few syntax issues. I formatted your code the best I could, hopefully you can now see the issues with you syntax.

Comment: This line is where the error is found: `let a = this._getWeather(function(apiurl), function(weather) {`  which has a syntax issue

Comment: I changed the code to this 

        function apiurl() {
       let apiurl = this._baseURL + '=' + (this.apikey);
       //var str = this._baseURL + '=' + (this.apikey);
        str = str.replace('=','');
        console.log(str); 
        }
and got the following from the logfile

        info t=2024-01-30T10:18:19Z bbcwx (instance 34): refreshing forecast at 10:18:19
        error t=2024-01-30T10:18:19Z this is undefined
        info t=2024-01-30T10:18:19Z Loaded desklet bbcwx@oak-wood.co.uk in 65 ms

Comment: It is somewhat strange that you put IN an `=` then take it out again `str = str.replace('=', '');`

Comment: im sorry, i cannot format that properly in a comment.

Comment: Don't put IN a comment, put it IN the question as perhaps "also tried" or some such

Comment: that is to eliminate a double `==` and turn it into a single in the api url. I need that cornfusing function to make the suntax of the website function correctly.

Comment: okay I'll do that now. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to  return the API URL from `apiurl()` and pass it to `_getWeather`:

```js
const getApiUrl = () => {
  let str = this._baseURL + '=' + (this.apikey);
  str = str.replace('=', '');
  return str;
}

let a = this._getWeather(getApiUrl(), (weather) => {
  if (weather) {
    this._load_forecast(weather);
  }
  deskletObj.displayForecast();
  deskletObj.displayCurrent();
  deskletObj.displayMeta();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, veelon. Im implementing that code now

Comment: Veelon, it resulted in:

`error t=2024-01-30T10:29:35Z 
[bbcwx@oak-wood.co.uk]: functions cannot be labelled
[bbcwx@oak-wood.co.uk]: Error importing desklet.js from bbcwx@oak-wood.co.uk
`

Comment: how would i correct this error?

error t=2024-01-30T10:18:19Z this is undefined`

Comment: 3limin4t0r, I made the changes you suggested up above and received the following response.

`missing ( before formal parameters`